# Segmentation Fault in Python 2.7.2 instead of IndexError

Tags: python, segmentation-fault

One of my programs was supposed to throw an `IndexError` with this code:

```
x = "Hello"
y = x[6]
```

However, instead of this, it returned a SegmentationFault:11. This was when I ran it in python 2.7.2. 
When I tried it in python 3.4.1, it threw the `IndexError`. Why might this be happening, and is there a way I can fix this? Thanks!

EDIT: 
Here's what I ran:

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = "Hello"
>>> x[6]
Segmentation fault: 11
```

whereas in python 3.4.1,

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = "hello"
>>> x[6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Can you post the complete output of the error?

Comment: Instead of just saying "code similar to this", can you produce [minimal example code that actually causes a segmentation fault when run](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Otherwise, all we can do is make wild guesses.

Comment: This is actually the exact code I was running. I was just learning the try...except syntax. I'll edit the post with the error as well.

Comment: Are those copy-pasted (not retyped, and not modified) from actual interpreter sessions? If so, try updating your 2.7.2 install to Python 2.7.8. That segfault shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate it [here](http://repl.it/Yn6). Perhaps it is specific to the earlier build or to the OSX version? This one is from a month later (and isn't running on OS X)

Comment: These are copy-pasted. I'll try updating and post the results

Answer (score 0):

Updating from python 2.7.2 to Python 2.7.8 fixes this problem.